# Microwave oven is not working but display works well

Tags: kitchens, microwave-oven

I recently moved to a new place. Since moving my Bosch microwave oven (model number: HLK4555EU/01 1) stopped working.
The user interface seems to be functional but it just doesn't start. While moving  it's door came out and my friends helped to put it back. Thereafter the problem remains.

Comment: What do you mean "it starts well" but also "it just didn't start?" And the door was broken & completely off?

Comment: @Xen2050 I mean it starts from the main switch(for display) but not for heating something.

Comment: make sure that the door closes properly ....... maybe the hinges are out of alignment ....... check the door ..... there are probably a couple of interlock tabs at the top of the door that fit into a rectangular opening in the oven front .... is a tab broken off?  ...... maybe post a picture of the oven with the door open

Answer (score 3):

#### "while moving it's door came out"

That's the key. A microwave oven is an extremely **safe** device as long as the door is closed when in use. It is an extremely **dangerous** device if it is used with the door open. In order to make absolutely certain that nobody will ever turn on a microwave oven with the door open, there are normally multiple interlocks or switches to make sure that it is closed before starting. These switches are **NOT** as obvious or as simple to override as, for example, the door-open-light-on switch for a refrigerator because the consequences are much more serious with a microwave oven.

A couple of likely possibilities:

- When the door came off, some internal wiring connected to the door came out and when you put the door back on the oven the wiring was not reconnected.
- A small hidden switch in the frame of the oven where the door closes was pulled/pushed out of place when the door came off and now when the door closes it doesn't trigger the switch correctly.

You may be able to figure this out by checking the schematic. What I do **NOT** recommend is trying to bypass the door switch because it only takes one accident to cause some serious damage.

Comment: Thanks, it's very valuable. Would you recommend it to do by oneself? Warranty is over it's pretty expensive(no one with reasonable price) for being repaired by a mechanic. May be using this [manual](https://www.bosch-home.co.uk/supportdetail/product/HLK4555EU/01#/Tabs=section-spareparts/)

Comment: That manual appears to be a parts ordering diagram. Which is helpful but doesn't explain "everything". Not much different from replacing parts inside a computer or other electronic device - if you are comfortable with that *and pay real attention to detail - e.g., different screw sizes, directions of connectors, etc.* then it can be a DIY job.

Answer (score 2):

The red circled parts appear to be microswitches, labeled `1)` and `2)`.

Part numbers are circled in yellow.

I think that they are behind the slots in the faceplate, circled in blue.

They are activated by the two latches on the door, circled in green. (copied from previous page)

One of the latches may not be engaging a switch because of a disconnected spring. (in green circle)

[image]

Comment: Very helpful! Will I need multi meter? Also do I need to take out the door again or it can be done without that(I'm really a novice)? Just one more question, can it happen that the power supply is not enough to start the microwave(360W, is less I know)? Because I see the display so I'm in doubt if it really is the problem. What would you think about it?

Comment: examine the latches on the door .... if the latches are not broken  and the springs are not disconnected, then **unplug the oven**, remove the covers and observe the operation of the microswitches ........... microswitches make a distinct clicking sound when activated ......... it seems that there are three interlock switches ..... probably, one is a "door closed" switch and the other two are "door latched"

Answer (score 1):

Your oven is damaged and the safety features which protect you from harm are stopping the oven from working.

If you try to fix this without skill or understanding you may create a dangerous hazard that may cause harm to you or other people.

See [US FDA Microwave Oven Radiation](https://www.fda.gov/radiation-emittingproducts/resourcesforyouradiationemittingproducts/ucm252762.htm)

> ### Have Radiation Injuries Resulted from Microwave Ovens?
>
> there have been very rare instances of radiation injury due to unusual circumstances or **improper servicing**.

(my emphasis)

> ### Checking Ovens for Leakage and Other Radiation Safety Problems
>
> There is little cause for concern about excess microwaves leaking from ovens unless the door hinges, latch, or seals are damaged. The FDA recommends looking at your oven carefully, and **not using an oven if the door doesn’t close firmly or is bent, warped, or otherwise damaged**.

and

> ### Tips on Safe Microwave Oven Operation
>
> - Don't operate a microwave oven if the door does not close firmly or is bent, warped, or otherwise damaged.
> - Stop using a microwave oven if it continues to operate with the door open.

---

> **can it happen that the power supply is not enough to start the microwave(360W, is less I know)?**

Generally no. If the display works, the problem is unlikely to be the power supply.

> **while moving it's door came out**

Almost certainly the safety interlocks are damaged.

It is certainly possible the door and its seals are dislocated, warped or damaged in a way that would cause the oven to leak microwave radiation if the safety interlocks are repaired. You need to be able to verify that there is no leakage after getting the oven to think all is well (it might not be).

---

> **Will I need multi meter? Also do I need to take out the door again or it can be done without that(I'm really a novice)?**

That last part is why I've written an answer with a somewhat negative tone.

Personally, I'd want to have [a device to measure radiation leakage](https://www.tester.co.uk/metrel-mld100-microwave-leakage-detector) levels and I would want to be able to check the correct operation of the safety interlocks.

I would only proceed with a fix/repair if I was certain that I understand the principles of the appliances operation, including the safety interlocks, and was certain I have the right knowledge and tools to make repairs to electrical appliances.

Many repairs involve some amount of disassembly and reassembly. So you need to be prepared for that.

I would happily spend hours (trying) to repair a vacuum-cleaner or induction-hob but wouldn't hesitate long before buying a new microwave oven rather than attempt to repair it's safety interlocks. Don't let me put you off repairing things, but please be sure you have a good understanding of the potential for harm before proceeding.